# $5x^{3}-5(p+1)x^{2}+(71p-1)x-(66p-1)=0$ has three solutions which are natural numbers?

Tags: polynomials

How find all values of parameter $p \in R$ such that equation $~ 5x^{3}-5(p+1)x^{2}+(71p-1)x-(66p-1)=0$ has three solutions which are natural numbers?

---

My try $(x - 1)(5x^2 - 5px + 66p - 1)=0$ and what next?

Comment: Better to put your attempt in the question body. This is a pre-emptive strike dispelling the thoughts (that will otherwise develop) that you are just outsourcing a homework problem. I took the liberty of moving it there.

Answer (score 3):

$5x^3-5(p+1)x^2+(71p-1)x-(66p-1)=(x-1)(5x^2-5px+66p-1)$, so now we need to know when $5x^2-5px+(66p-1)$ has two integer roots.

Let theese roots be $a$ and $b$. Then $a+b=p$, $ab=(66p-1)/5$. So, $5ab=66(a+b)-1$, and we can write this as $25ab-330(a+b)+5=0$, or $(5a-66)(5b-66)=66^2-5=4351=19\cdot 229$.

So, the only opportinities (if we don't look at order of $a$ and $b$) we can have are:

$5a-66=4351$, $5b-66=1$, what doesn't hold for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$

$5a-66=19$, $5b-66=229$, which means $p=a+b=17+59=76$.

$5a-66=-19$, $5b-66=-229$, doesn't hold for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

$5a-66=-4351$, $5b-66=-1$, which means $p=a+b=-857+13=-844$ but in this case $a=-857$ is not a natural number.

So, answer is $p=76$ (if I didn't miscount).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x=1$ is always an integer root, so we have
$$
5x^3-5(p+1)x^2+(71p-1)x-(66p-1)=(x-1)(5x^2- 5px + 66p - 1).
$$
Hence we can reduce the question to the quadratc polynomial equation
$$
5x^2- 5px + 66p - 1=0.
$$
For which real parameters $p$ does it have two integral roots ? 
Using Vieta we see that there are exactly two possibilities:
$p=-844$, with $x=1,13,-857$ as integral roots, and 
$p=76$, with $x=1,17,59$ as integral roots.

Comment: $\Delta>0$,$25p^2 - 1320p + 20>0$,$\frac{66p-1}{5} \in N$

$p>52$,$p=76$ is only solution?